# How to paginate the filtered results in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to paginate the filtered results in php mysql?

My pagination displays only all files that is stored in database but when I want to search for example, all records of remarks interviewed, it will display all files having remarks interviewed, then in 2nd page it still displays the filtered results.

My problem is when I click the pagination, the second page will retrieve again all files that is stored in database. I want the second page is the filtered results.

```
    `<?php 
    include 'functions.php';
    ob_start();

    if(!loggedin())
    { header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
     }

    if(isset($_POST['edit']))
     {

    $_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
     header("Location:edit.php");
    }

     if(isset($_POST['BOOK']))
        {
    $_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
    header("Location:booking_edit.php");}


        if($_POST['types'] == 'name' || $_POST['types'] == 'mobile' || $_POST['types'] ==       'OccasionType')
    {
    $_SESSION['filter']=$_POST['filter'];
     }

     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
     <title>Manorama Party Plot</title>
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexigrid.css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js">           </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    // Datepicker
        $('#From,#To').datepicker({
    inline: true
    });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
        </script>        
        <script type="text/javascript">     
       $(document).ready(function() {     
       $('#types').change(function(){     
      if($('#types').val() === 'InquiryDate' || $('#types').val() === 'OccasionDate')     
     {     
     $('#From').show();
      $('#To').show(); 
      $('#filter').hide();     
     }     
      else    
     {
    $('#filter').show();         
     $('#From').hide();
     $('#To').hide();        
     }     
      });     
     });     
      </script> 


      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexigrid.js"></script>


     </head>
     <body>



      <div class="wrapper filter_wrapper">
     <div id="header">
       <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div></div>
    <div class="fillter_con">
     <div class="flexigrid fillter">
             <div class="pDiv">
                <div class="pDiv2 axport">
                <h2>Filter :</h2>  



       <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' name='form_filter'> 
       <select class="filter_select" id="types" name="types">
                <option value="none">none</option>
                    <option value="name">name</option> 
                    <option value="mobile">mobile</option> 
                    <option value="OccasionType">OccasionType</option>
                    <option value="InquiryDate">InquiryDate</option>
                    <option value="OccasionDate">OccasionDate</option> 
             </select> 
              <input class="filter_input" name="filter" id="filter" type="text" > 
          <input type="text" class="filter_input" id="From" name="From" style="display:  none;" va  lue="From" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='From':this.value=this.value"  onfocus="this.value=='From'?this.value='':this.value=this.value" /> 
          <input type="text" class="filter_input" id="To" name="To" style="display: none;" value="To" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='To':this.value=this.value" onfocus="this.value=='To'?this.value='':this.value=this.value" />  
                  <input class="filter_button" type='submit' value = 'Go'> 
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

        $tbl_name="visitor_detail"; $adjacents = 3;

    if($_POST['types'] == 'name') {  
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE    name='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
    }  
       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'mobile') { 
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE mobile='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
    } 
       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE OccasionType='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
     } 

       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') { 
       $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE TodayDate between '".$_POST['From']."' and '".$_POST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC"; 
       }

       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
         $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE date between '".$_POST['From']."' and '".$_POST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
         }

    else { 
         $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
    }

    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "all_inquiry.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;

     $page = $_GET['page'];

    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on       this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0



     if($_POST['types'] == 'name') {  

      $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE name='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id   DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
       }  
      elseif($_POST['types'] == 'mobile') {  

       $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE mobile='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT $start, $limit ";  
      } 
       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  

      $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE OccasionType='".$_SESSION['filter']."'   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
       } 

      elseif($_POST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') {  
      $que="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE TodayDate between '".$_POST['From']."' and   '".$_POST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit" ;  
     }

       elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
      $que="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE date between '".$_POST['From']."' and '".$_POST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit" ;  
     }

       else {  
       $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
    } 

      $sql = mysql_query($que);


    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is   given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous   page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items  per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"><div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                <span></span>
                </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";

        else
            $pagination.= "<div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                <span></span>
                </div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";  

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<div    class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?  page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                   
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<div  class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></div>";
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></div>";      
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents  * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=1\">1</a></div>";
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a></div>";
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= " <div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage? page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                    
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\"><div   class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\">
                     </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\"></div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
        if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no  page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous  page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"><div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                <span></span>
                </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";

        else
            $pagination.= "<div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                <span></span>
                </div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";  

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";     
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= " <div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";     
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\"><div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\">
                     </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\"></div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }?>  

  <div id="flexme1"><table>
            <thead>
                   <tr>

                    <th width="100"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                    <th width="90"><strong>Mobile</strong></th>
                    <th width="75"><strong>Occasion Type</strong></th>
                    <th width="80"><strong>Occasion Date</strong></th>
                    <th width="70"><strong>Approx Gust</strong></th>
                    <th width="150"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                    <th width="150"><strong>Address</strong></th>
                    <th width="120"><strong>Email</strong></th>
                    <th width="75"><strong>Other Contact</strong></th>

                    <th width="70"><strong>Enquiry Date</strong></th>
                    <th width="80"><strong>Author</strong></th>
                    <th width="100"><strong>Action</strong></th>

                </tr>
            </thead></table>


           <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?>

     <form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> 

            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <tbody> 

                 <tr>   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['0']; ?>" >
                    <td><?php echo $data['2']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['3']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['8']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['9']; ?></td>          
                    <td><?php echo $data['10']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['11']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['4']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['5']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['6']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['12']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['13']; ?></td>
                    <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit">
                    <input  name="BOOK" type="submit" value="Book" style="color:#d90f0f">

                    </td>
                    </tr>



            </tbody>
             </table>
             </form>
             <?php } ?></div>


            <div class="flexigrid">
            <div class="pDiv">
            <div class="pDiv2">


              <div class="pGroup">
              <select name="rp" id="rp"  >
              <option value="10">10&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
              <option value="15">15&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
              <option value="20">20&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
              <option value="30">30&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
              <option value="50">50&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
              </select>
              </div> 
              <div class="btnseparator"></div>
               <?=$pagination?>


                      <div class="axport">
                      <h2>Export</h2>
                        <div class="pGroup">
                            <div class="pdf_button  pButton">PDF</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btnseparator"></div>
                        <div class="pGroup">
        <?php 
         $types = $_POST['types'];
       $filter = $_POST['filter'];
       $from = $_POST['From'];
        $to = $_POST['To'];
        ?>
                            <div class="excel_button pButton">
                            <form action="excel.php"   method="POST">
                            <input name="types" type="hidden"     value="<?php echo $types;?>">
                            <input name="filter" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $filter;?>">
                            <input name="from" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $from;?>">
                            <input name="to" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $to;?>">                           
                            <input type="submit" value="Excel"> 
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>




        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#flexme1').flexigrid();
        });
        //]]>
        </script>
        </div>
         </div>
        <div id="footer">
         <p>Copyright © <span><a href="#">Aum Digital Marketing</a></span> , All rights    reserved</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the same query and add `LIMIT 11, 20` ?

Comment: When you click the pagination link you need to send the search parameters again .. along with page number .. are you doing this can you please post the relevant portion of your code .. ?

Comment: @new_developer hay i have post my code here...hope you can give me update regards my question..

Comment: @user1680044  I cannot run your code but based on my understanding I am changing it .. see my answer .. and try to capture the main idea ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated code

```
`<?php 
                           include 'functions.php';
                           ob_start();

                           if(!loggedin())
                           { header("Location:login.php");
                           exit();
                            }

                           if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))
                            {

                           $_SESSION['id']=$_REQUEST['id'];
                            header("Location:edit.php");
                           }

                            if(isset($_REQUEST['BOOK']))
                               {
                           $_SESSION['id']=$_REQUEST['id'];
                           header("Location:booking_edit.php");}


                               if($_REQUEST['types'] == 'name' || $_REQUEST['types'] == 'mobile' || $_REQUEST['types'] ==       'OccasionType')
                           {
                           $_SESSION['filter']=$_REQUEST['filter'];
                            }

                            ?>
                            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                           <html>
                            <head>
                           <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
                            <title>Manorama Party Plot</title>
                             <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexigrid.css" media="all" />

                           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
                               <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

                               <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js">           </script>

                               <script type="text/javascript">
                           $(function(){

                           // Datepicker
                               $('#From,#To').datepicker({
                           inline: true
                           });

                                       //hover states on the static widgets
                                       $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                                           function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                                           function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                                       );

                                   });
                               </script>        
                               <script type="text/javascript">     
                              $(document).ready(function() {     
                              $('#types').change(function(){     
                             if($('#types').val() === 'InquiryDate' || $('#types').val() === 'OccasionDate')     
                            {     
                            $('#From').show();
                             $('#To').show(); 
                             $('#filter').hide();     
                            }     
                             else    
                            {
                           $('#filter').show();         
                            $('#From').hide();
                            $('#To').hide();        
                            }     
                             });     
                            });     
                             </script> 


                             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexigrid.js"></script>


                            </head>
                            <body>



                             <div class="wrapper filter_wrapper">
                            <div id="header">
                              <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
                           </div>
                           <div id="content"></div></div>
                           <div class="fillter_con">
                            <div class="flexigrid fillter">
                                    <div class="pDiv">
                                       <div class="pDiv2 axport">
                                       <h2>Filter :</h2>  



                              <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' name='form_filter'> 
                              <select class="filter_select" id="types" name="types">
                                       <option value="none">none</option>
                                           <option value="name">name</option> 
                                           <option value="mobile">mobile</option> 
                                           <option value="OccasionType">OccasionType</option>
                                           <option value="InquiryDate">InquiryDate</option>
                                           <option value="OccasionDate">OccasionDate</option> 
                                    </select> 
                                     <input class="filter_input" name="filter" id="filter" type="text" > 
                                 <input type="text" class="filter_input" id="From" name="From" style="display:  none;" va  lue="From" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='From':this.value=this.value"  onfocus="this.value=='From'?this.value='':this.value=this.value" /> 
                                 <input type="text" class="filter_input" id="To" name="To" style="display: none;" value="To" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='To':this.value=this.value" onfocus="this.value=='To'?this.value='':this.value=this.value" />  
                                         <input class="filter_button" type='submit' value = 'Go'> 
                                       </form>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>

                               <?php

                               $tbl_name="visitor_detail"; $adjacents = 3;

                           if($_REQUEST['types'] == 'name') {  
                           $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE    name='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                           }  
                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'mobile') { 
                             $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE mobile='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                           } 
                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  
                            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE OccasionType='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                            } 

                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') { 
                              $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE TodayDate between '".$_REQUEST['From']."' and '".$_REQUEST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC"; 
                              }

                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
                                $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE date between '".$_REQUEST['From']."' and '".$_REQUEST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                                }

                           else { 
                                $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
                           }

                           $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
                           $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

                           /* Setup vars for query. */
                           $targetpage = "all_inquiry.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
                           $limit = 10;

                            $page = $_GET['page'];

                           if($page) 
                               $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on       this page
                           else
                               $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0



                            if($_REQUEST['types'] == 'name') {  

                             $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE name='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id   DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
                              }  
                             elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'mobile') {  

                              $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE mobile='".$_SESSION['filter']."' ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT $start, $limit ";  
                             } 
                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  

                             $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE OccasionType='".$_SESSION['filter']."'   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
                              } 

                             elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') {  
                             $que="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE TodayDate between '".$_REQUEST['From']."' and   '".$_REQUEST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit" ;  
                            }

                              elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
                             $que="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE date between '".$_REQUEST['From']."' and '".$_REQUEST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit" ;  
                            }

                              else {  
                              $que = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";  
                           } 

                             $sql = mysql_query($que);

                             if(isset($_REQUEST))
                             {
                               unset($_REQUEST['page']);
                               $queryString = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
                             }

                           if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is   given, default to 1.
                           $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous   page is page - 1
                           $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
                           $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items  per page, rounded up.
                           $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

                           /* 
                               Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
                               We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
                           */
                           $pagination = "";
                           if($lastpage > 1)
                           {   
                               $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
                               //previous button
                               if ($page > 1) 
                                   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&$queryString\"><div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                                       <span></span>
                                       </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";

                               else
                                   $pagination.= "<div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                                       <span></span>
                                       </div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";  

                               //pages 
                               if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                               {   
                                   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                   {
                                       if ($counter == $page)
                                           $pagination.= "<div    class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                       else
                                           $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?  page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                   
                                   }
                               }
                               elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
                               {
                                   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                                   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                                   {
                                       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= "<div  class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                       }
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=$lpm1&$queryString\">$lpm1</a></div>";
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=$lastpage&$queryString\">$lastpage</a></div>";      
                                   }
                                   //in middle; hide some front and some back
                                   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents  * 2))
                                   {
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage? page=1&$queryString\">1</a></div>";
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\"><a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&$queryString\">2</a></div>";
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                                       for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= " <div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                       }
                                       $pagination.= "...";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&$queryString\">$lpm1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&$queryString\">$lastpage</a>";       
                                   }
                                   //close to end; only hide early pages
                                   else
                                   {
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&$queryString\">1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&$queryString\">2</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">...</div>";
                                       for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage? page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                    
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               //next button
                               if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                                   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\&$queryString"><div   class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\">
                                            </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
                               else
                                   $pagination.= "<div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\"></div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
                               $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
                           }
                               if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no  page var is given, default to 1.
                           $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous  page is page - 1
                           $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
                           $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
                           $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

                           /* 
                               Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
                               We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
                           */
                           $pagination = "";
                           if($lastpage > 1)
                           {   
                               $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
                               //previous button
                               if ($page > 1) 
                                   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&$queryString\"><div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                                       <span></span>
                                       </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";

                               else
                                   $pagination.= "<div class=\"pPrev pButton pGroup\">
                                       <span></span>
                                       </div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";  

                               //pages 
                               if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                               {   
                                   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                   {
                                       if ($counter == $page)
                                           $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                       else
                                           $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                   }
                               }
                               elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
                               {
                                   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                                   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                                   {
                                       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                       }
                                       $pagination.= "...";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&$queryString\">$lpm1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage&$queryString\">$lastpage</a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";     
                                   }
                                   //in middle; hide some front and some back
                                   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                                   {
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1&$queryString\">1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&$queryString\">2</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "...";
                                       for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= " <div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                       }
                                       $pagination.= "...";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1&$queryString\">$lpm1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpag&$queryStringe\">$lastpage</a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";     
                                   }
                                   //close to end; only hide early pages
                                   else
                                   {
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2&$queryString\">2</a>";
                                       $pagination.= "...";
                                       for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                       {
                                           if ($counter == $page)
                                               $pagination.= "<div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div>";
                                           else
                                               $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&$queryString\"><div class=\"pGroup\">$counter</div></a>";                 
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               //next button
                               if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                                   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next&$queryString\"><div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\">
                                            </div></a><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
                               else
                                   $pagination.= "<div class=\"pNext pButton pGroup\"></div><div class=\"btnseparator\"></div>";
                               $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
                           }?>  

                         <div id="flexme1"><table>
                                   <thead>
```

Comment: @user1680044 great ... njoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read the question body but the magic wand you need is called [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query)

Just use it to form your pagination links to preserve all filtering options